# How to create javascript function for hovering 3 or 4 element at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to hover 3 item at a time. when i will put cursor one of them. It should hover other two item. 
please can help me anyone. i want to do this with javascript. I have make a model but it is not good. i want to use with function so i can use this again and again. please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.boxes {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width:150px;
    height:100px
}
.box1 {
    width:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin:0px;
    height: 20px;
}

.box4 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    height: 100px;
}


</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // box 1
    $('.box1').mouseover(function(){
        $('.box1').css('background-color', '#F7FE2E');
        $('.box4').css('background-color', '#F7FE2E');
        $('.hov').css('color', '#0f0');

    });
    $('.box1').mouseout(function(){
        $('.box1').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('.box4').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('.hov').css('color', '#fff');

    });
       $('.box4').mouseover(function(){
        $('.box4').css('background-color', '#F7FE2E');
        $('.box1').css('background-color', '#F7FE2E');
        $('.hov').css('color', '#0f0');

    });
    $('.box4').mouseout(function(){
        $('.box4').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('.box1').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        $('.hov').css('color', '#fff');

    });

});

</script>
</head>

<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box1">Box 1</div>

</div>
<div class="box4"><a href="#" class="hov">box4</a> </div>
<br/>
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box1">Box 1</div>

</div>
<div class="box4"><a href="#" class="hov">box4</a> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems very counter-intuitive for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group your divs by parent divs, you can use the HTML structure to determine what to highlight.  I don't know your exact usage model, but something like this:

```
<div class="boxgroup">
    <div class="box1 hover"></div>
    <div class="box2 hover"><a href="mylink" class="hov">Link</a></div>
</div>

<div class="boxgroup">
    <div class="box1 hover"></div>
    <div class="box2 hover"><a href="mylink" class="hov">Link</a></div>
</div>
```

And then in your jQuery:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.hover', function () {
    var boxgroup = $(this).closest('.boxgroup');
    boxgroup.find('.hover').addClass('hovercolor');
    boxgroup.find('.hov').css('color', '#0f0');
}).on('mouseout', '.hover', function () {
    var boxgroup = $(this).closest('.boxgroup');
    boxgroup.find('.hover').removeClass('hovercolor');
    boxgroup.find('.hov').css('color', '#000');
});
```

Here, I use `.closest()` to find what group the `div` is in, and then highlight all of the other `.hover` items in that group.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/HZtVP/3/

If you want your divs to not be physically grouped, there are other ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. use a mapping javascript object.
2. and use class 'like' selector to bind functions to elements which have class starting with ".box"

eg :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mapping = { 'box1':'box4','box4':'box1' };

    $("[class^=box]").mouseover(function(){
       .........

    });
```