# for hovering 3 items at a time with javascript using same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create javascript function for hovering 3 or 4 element at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579369/how-to-create-javascript-function-for-hovering-3-or-4-element-at-a-time)

I want to hover 3 element at a time. when i will put cursor one of them. It should hover other two item. i want to do this with javascript.
please see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Taslimkhan/wTcTU/14/

I have used class three times in my html document. when i hover on 1st box set it show all box hover. 
but i need: 
when i will hover box 1 it should show only A box, and when i will hover A box it should show only box1,

when i will hover box 2 it should show only B box, and when i will hover B box it should show only box2,

same behaviour should do for third set of box.

I cant use same class two times. but I want to use same class. again and again. but how can i do them? please help me.

There are code i have used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// box 1
$('.box1').mouseover(function(){
    $('.box1').css('background-color', '#F7FE2E');
    $('.box4').css('background-color', '#F7FE2E');
    $('.hov').css('color', '#0f0');

});
$('.box1').mouseout(function(){
    $('.box1').css('background-color', '#FFF');
    $('.box4').css('background-color', '#FFF');
    $('.hov').css('color', '#fff');

});
```

Comment: this two question are mine. please have you any answer?

Comment: Do not ask questions twice.  If you need better answers, edit your original question to be more specific, or comment on answers that are already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my variant:

```
var $boxes = $('.box');
$boxes.hover(function() {
    $boxes.filter('.' + $(this).data('set')).addClass('active');
}, function() {
    $boxes.filter('.' + $(this).data('set')).removeClass('active');
});
```

I removed unnecessary code duplications and made use of `data-set` attribute to reference corresponding boxes which needs to be highlighted.

I also encourage you not to use `.css` method to style HTML. You should use CSS classes instead to make code cleaner.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/wTcTU/21/

Comment: your answer is short and nice. thanks for that but i havent understood about class. where was the class wrong. please can you cleare me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve. Only make one box yellow each time?

this works, but I would change the markup a little bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/wTcTU/19/

```
$(".box1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});

$(".box1").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().css("background-color", "white");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});

$(".box4").mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).prev().find(".box1").css("background-color", "yellow");
     $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});

$(".box4").mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).prev().find(".box1").css("background-color", "white");
     $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Comment: your answer is absolutely correct. Thank you very much for this nice answer.